# Inserting particular values into different rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a simple task to do, sadly I am stuck. I have two tables: `Countries` and `Continents`.

`Countries` has these columns:

```
CountryID, CountryName, ContinentID.
```

`Continents` has these columns :

```
ContinentID, ContinentName.
```

Now, I need to insert particular `ContinentId` into `Countries.ContinentID` i.e `1. Belgium 1`.

I would like to write a `INSERT INTO` query, that will allow me to insert one value of `ContinentID` to multiple rows of `CountryID`. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `update` statement:

```
update Countries set ContinentID = 1
--values (1,2,3,4,5,6) are just for example
where CountryID in (1,2,3,4,5,6)
```

Comment: I'll try that, be back in a second!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly

you can use `SELECT` in your insert statement

example:

```
INSERT INTO Countries (CountryID)
SELECT ContinentID FROM Continents GROUP BY ContinentName
```

Comment: Pretty much what I had in mind, but is there a condition I can add to group up Countries and give them particular ContinentID?

Comment: something like this? SELECT ContinentID FROM Continents GROUP BY ContinentName